# This, stage & parent are null

Tags: actionscript-3

Im trying to access the stage from an external class this is what I have:

*Player.as (Main Class)*

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Player extends MovieClip 
{

    private var _controls:Controls;

    public function Player()
    {
        // constructor code
        _controls = new Controls();
    }
}
```

*Controls.as*

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Controls extends MovieClip
{
    private var _playbtn:MovieClip;

    public function Controls()
    {
        trace(this.getChildByName("playbtn"));
    }

}
```

but this line `trace(this.getChildByName("playbtn"));` always errors I have even tried:

```
trace(stage.getChildByName("playbtn"));
trace(parent.getChildByName("playbtn"));
```

But I get the same error:

> Null for this and
>
> Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. for
>   stage & parent

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mistaken as to what `getChildByName` actually does. It returns reference to an object with its `name` property set to the supplied value. It **does not** return a reference to an object set to a variable with the supplied name.

For a reference to be returned by `getChildByName`, you must instantiate an object, set its `name` to something, and then call `addChild` on a `DisplayObjectContainer` with that object. Then you can call `getChildByName` on the `DisplayObjectContainer`.

For future reference, `stage` will be null until the object is added to the stage. `parent` will be null until the object is used in an `addChild` call

Answer (score 1):

Display objects get access to their 'stage' property when they are added to the stage. You haven't added the _controls to the stage ( eg addChild(_controls) ) when you try to access the stage property.
Add an event listener (Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE) to the constructor of your Controls class that points to a handler that then checks the stage property.

Comment: All the MovieClips I want to have access to are already on the stage. Added manually (not via addChild - or code). If I do a trace inside `Player.as` such as `trace(this.getChildByName("playbtn"));` I get the `[object MovieClip]` so how come I can't do this inside `Controls.as`?

Comment: MovieClips have a .name property that is independent from the name of the VARIABLE they are instantiated with. I think you're getting the error because "playbtn" is referring to _playbtn.name and that has not been set to "playbtn".

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding everything to the stage manually, there is no need to create a new instance of Controls in the constructor of Player, you should just retrieve the reference:

`_controls = this.controls; //where 'controls' is the instance name you assigned in Flash IDE`.

Also, where is the 'playbtn' instace you are trying to retrieve? Is it on the stage or is inside of the Controls instance? As you are tracing `this.getChildByName("playbtn");` it HAS TO be inside of Controls with the instance name playbtn assigned in the IDE (or via .name property).

You are getting indeed a null for parent and stage because you have not added the instance to the stage. What you are doing right now:

1. You instantiate Player, the player then instantiates the Controls (it does not retrieve the reference you have on stage, because you are calling it with the `new` keyword!)
2. The new controls have never been added to anything, therefore they have no parent and neither stage.

Comment: The reason why I did `_controls = new Controls();` is because I could not get anything to work without it, for example the constructor code would not run, I could even make deliberate errors/mistakes and they would not be picked up in compiler errors.

Comment: That's weird. (however, I have experienced a lot of weird stuff with Flash...) In that case simply remove the controller from the stage in the IDE and add this controller with addChild().